# How enable all CONSTRAINT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE sales
(ord INTEGER NOT NULL,
ship INTEGER NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE sales
ADD CONSTRAINT order_check CHECK(ord < 10);
```

Then I disabled my `CONSTRAINT` :

```
ALTER TABLE sales NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
INSERT INTO sales VALUES(10,1)

SELECT * FROM sales
```

How enable all my `CONSTRAINT` now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273(SQL.90).aspx):

```
ALTER TABLE sales CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
ALTER TABLE sales CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
```

Answer (score 1):

`CHECK` :

```
ALTER TABLE sales CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
```